# How do I stop javascript from redirecting the page?

Tags: javascript, ads

We run a few popular websites and are having issues with ads redirecting mobile users to other websites and app stores when the page loads. Is there a way to block javascript from changing the url?

I have a couple ideas but haven't made anything work yet:

- use beforeunload to stop from directing away from the page but I need away to tell if the user meant to leave by clicking on something
- use window.MutationObserver to monitor DOM but I'm not sure this can be used to monitor changes to window.location

Anyone have a solution?

**UPDATE**

I tried the suggestion below to add the "sandbox" attribute to the iframe that holds the ad. On my test page it did stop my page from running the redirect but it didn't stop the ad redirects when I made this live! So I'm guessing they are redirecting the page with another method that gets through the sandbox block. Anyone have any ideas how they could be doing this?

```
example iframe:
<iframe sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts" ..

example iframe html (redirect):
window.top.location.href = "example.com";
```

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but you really should report that to your ad service, or drop them.

Comment: Indeed, I agree with @Nick you really should have a word with whoever is providing those ads.  The minute you are using JavaScript in anger to fight against ads you are allowing on your site, you are fighting a losing battle.

Comment: We use more than a dozen ad exchanges and have tried to tell them all. Apparently this is an industry wide problem and everyone is experiencing it. We can't find a way to log the information either to figure out who it is.

Comment: @ChrisR. it's going to be tough.  You can try using beforeunload with preventDefault(), but my guess is you are going to have varying success in different browsers.

Comment: @NickDelaney, I'm looking for any solution that can at least reduce the number of people this happens to. Or at the least a way to log when it happens so we can report it.

Comment: @ChrisR. are the ads inside an iframe?

Comment: @NickDelaney, Yes, the ads are inside an iframe. That's why I'm surprised they can even direct the page as I thought you can't do that from inside an iframe. We've only seen this happen on mobile. (I've personally seen it on iphone 6 with built in browser. not sure what other phones are effected)

Answer (score 1):

If the ads are in an iFrame add the `sandbox` attribute to the iFrame tag.  Per w3schools it will prevent the following...

- treat the content as being from a unique origin
- block form submission
- block script execution
- disable APIs
- prevent links from targeting
  other browsing contexts
- prevent the content to navigate its top-level browsing context
- block automatically triggered features (such as automatically playing a video or automatically focusing a form control)

**NOTE** - this is a HTML5 feature, and won't work in older browsers

Comment: I forgot about the sandbox attribute. I'll create a test page for this. But if we allow script execution for the ads to work won't it be the same situation? Or if we do this "<iframe sandbox='allow-scripts'>" but exclude 'allow-top-navigation' then maybe that would work?

Comment: I implemented this (sandbox = "allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-scripts") on every iframe that contains an ad on our site. I setup a test page which did work in blocking my javascript from running (window.top.location.href = "http://www.example.com";). But it didn't stop the redirects from the ads! I browsed on my phone for 20 minutes then I got a mobile redirect. How are they getting them through an iframe which has the sandbox feature? This is on safari on iphone 6.

Comment: @ChrisR. try removing allow-scripts from sandbox.  I believe it's the scripts that are creating the redirect

Comment: We added the sandbox attribute to all our iframes 2 days ago but we are still getting reports of mobile redirects and I got one myself too. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

When using standard javascript tags, the easiest solution is to increase your mobile tag floors above ~$0.45 (you should not need to go higher than $0.55).

For the most part we see mobile redirects mostly come in on 300x250 sizes, but have also seen it on 728x90 particularly when displayed on mobile (as 728x90 is more geared for desktop and demand for that size is extremely low on mobile meaning the bad ads win by paying a cheaper price).

If you are using prebid.js, other header bidding or multi-bid tags, in most cases you will have the ability to programmatically inspect the ad payload before you append the unit code to the page.

This provides an excellent opportunity to regex / search the ad payload string for code that sets window.location, and enables the developer to take specific actions when detected (such as bypass the bad ad and instead display a trusted remnant solution or house ad).